# CodeMirror - multiplication Code block

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, codemirror

I have problem with plugin: Codemirror.
Plugin works good but when I try connect with bootstrap modal that is problem.

1) When I click first time that is ok (1 code block)
2) When I close first modal and run second time that is: 3 code block (duplicate)
3) When I close second modal and run third time that is: 6 code block (duplicate)

My code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="code-editor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="">Edytor elementu</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="code"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" name="close">Anuluj</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" name="save">Zapisz</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('[data-element-id]').append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit-element"></i>').css({position: 'relative'});
  $('body').on( 'click', '[data-element-id] i.edit-element', function(){
    var code = $(this).parent();
    var code_new = code.clone();
     code_new.find('i.edit-element').remove();
    $('#code-editor').modal('show');

    $('#code-editor').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      editor = CodeMirror($('#code-editor #code')[0], {
        mode: "text/html",
        lineNumbers: false,
        value: '<h1>Example text</h1>'
      });
    });
    $('#code-editor button[name="save"]').on('click',function(){
      code.html(editor.getValue()).append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit-element"></i>');
    });
  });
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/front/plugins/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="assets/front/plugins/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="assets/front/plugins/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
```

And image:
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAoeN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution:

use `.off('click')`
example:

```
$('body').off('click').on( 'click', '[data-element-id] i.edit-element', function(){
```